# How do I check the battery status with a Fujifilm S9900?

Tags: battery

I have a Fujifilm S9900 but was wondering if there is any way to check the status of the batteries that I am using and when I need to get new ones - besides when the low battery light flickers. Does anyone know where that might be?

It takes 4 AA batteries.

Answer (score 1):

In shooting mode, there is a low/empty battery indicator on the lower right. (It's marked as 23 in the diagram of the display indications on [page 4 of the manual](http://www.fujifilm.com/support/digital_cameras/manuals/pdf/index/s/finepix_s9900w-s9800-s9700_manual_en.pdf#page=16)). It does not tell you the level of charge left in the batteries, so I don't think there's a way of doing that, other than to take the batteries out of the camera and test them, by discharging them.

If it's not giving you an accurate report on the state of the battery, make sure that you have correctly set the battery type you are using (lithium, alkaline, or NiMh) in the preferences (see [page 10 of the manual](http://www.fujifilm.com/support/digital_cameras/manuals/pdf/index/s/finepix_s9900w-s9800-s9700_manual_en.pdf#page=22)).

It may just be best to get in the habit of using rechargeable batteries, and "topping them up" them after every use of the camera.